# how can I use useRef to treat the div as textarea

Tags: html, reactjs, input

I have a long message saved as html format. I want to show this message to the screen without Html element as textarea input.

```
message = <p>Mobil &auml ........ </p>
```

Before I upgrade React version to V6 it was working fine as the code below.
I could scroll down and adjust the textarea box size to see the message inside the box.

```
<div 
     id="textarea" 
     name="message"
     className="form-control" 
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.message }} 
     ref="textarea"
 />
```

after updating to React V6, when I write exactly the same code, it gives me an error saying

"Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead. Learn more about using refs safely here".

My first approach was to just simply delete   ref="textarea" but then the message is overflow from the box and cannot read other information below.

And my second approach is to use useRef() but im not really understanding how to incorporate it to my code.

any suggestion here plz.

Answer (score 0):

First option:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function Teste() {
  const divElement = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (divElement.current) {
      divElement.current.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea')).value = 'Hello World';
    }
  });

  return <div ref={divElement} />;
}

export default Teste;
```

Second option:

https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/utilities/slot